# Differences and advantages of using libGDX or Android SDK?

Tags: android, libgdx

Which are the main advantages of using libGDX? Is there some difference between libGDX and Android SDK, or libGDX is just like a framework that uses Android SDK? Which one you advise me to use?

Comment: What are you trying to make?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm trying to make an android game

Comment: I would go with libgdx. You'll have a much easier time setting up audio and input controls. Plus, there is way more you can do with the graphics using shaders (if you want to), and you can seemlessly incorporate 3D. And you can compile and test on your desktop very quickly compared to pushing to device or emulator, so you can do very fast iterations of code to fix problems and debug issues that aren't specific to Android hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all i want to say, that this question is a bit opinion based and so i think it will be closed soon. Anyway i want to point out an important thing:
Libgdx is a crossplattform framework. You can develop and test 99% of your game on desktop. Then add aview code lines and it runs on android to. The only difference between the android app and the desktop version are then the Sensors and the Touchscreen. You may also get problems with the Screen sizes, but for this there are solutions you should take a look at.
I never worked with the android sdk, but as much as i know you have to use the emulator or your phone for testing. So the testing process is really slow and annoying.
And also if you want to develop for Android phones only, why don't you spent 5 minutes in thinking about how to controll your game on desktop and add those few lines?
Thats the thing i wanted to point out. The rest is up to you.
Maybe you want to take a look at the video [on this page](http://hackedprojects.blogspot.it/2012/03/android-sdk-vs-andengine-vs-libgdx.html).